# What does this dracut log output mean? Why is there an infinite loop?

Tags: centos, boot, initramfs, dracut

I'm fighting a server with Centos 7 that doesn't start. I've no idea why. I found that I can pass the `rd.debug` parameter to the kernel and it logs a LOT of dracut initialization messages. 1.6MB in fact. But most of it consists of the same lines, looping over and over again. Looks like an infinite loop, but there are no error messages. The very start is *slightly* different, so I've included that together with a few more iterations. This is still happening in initramfs, before mounting true root.

**What is going on here?**

```
[   20.924158] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@47(): check_finished
[   20.933032] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@431(check_finished): local f
[   20.941570] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   20.950154] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   20.958722] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' ']'
[   20.967520] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh'
[   20.976345] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/root ']'
[   20.985159] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   20.993969] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.002889] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' ']'
[   21.011917] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh'
[   21.020977] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/swap ']'
[   21.030048] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.039160] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.048346] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' ']'
[   21.057785] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh'
[   21.067222] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/mapper/centos-root ']'
[   21.076621] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.086258] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.095885] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' ']'
[   21.105455] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh'
[   21.115105] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/vg_home/lv_home ']'
[   21.124914] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): return 1
[   21.134798] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@50(): udevadm settle --timeout=0
[   21.144729] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@53(): sleep 0.5
[   21.154717] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@55(): for i in '/run/systemd/ask-password/ask.*'
[   21.164760] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@56(): '[' -e '/run/systemd/ask-password/ask.*' ']'
[   21.174884] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@59(): '[' 0 -gt 240 ']'
[   21.185175] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@69(): main_loop=1
[   21.195448] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@70(): '[' 1 -gt 360 ']'
[   21.205684] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@24(): :
[   21.216064] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@26(): check_finished
[   21.226445] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@431(check_finished): local f
[   21.236700] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.246920] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.257089] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' ']'
[   21.267068] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh'
[   21.277134] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/root ']'
[   21.287487] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.297273] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.307010] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' ']'
[   21.316577] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh'
[   21.326253] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/swap ']'
[   21.335954] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.345554] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.355244] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' ']'
[   21.364944] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh'
[   21.374640] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/mapper/centos-root ']'
[   21.384273] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.393938] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.403616] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' ']'
[   21.413157] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh'
[   21.422535] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/vg_home/lv_home ']'
[   21.432173] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): return 1
[   21.441776] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@28(): udevadm settle --exit-if-exists=/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/work
[   21.451244] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@30(): check_finished
[   21.460542] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@431(check_finished): local f
[   21.469746] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.478975] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.488124] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' ']'
[   21.488453] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh'
[   21.497478] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/root ']'
[   21.498072] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.507368] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.507813] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' ']'
[   21.517275] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh'
[   21.517692] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/swap ']'
[   21.527214] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.527625] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.537287] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' ']'
[   21.537618] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh'
[   21.547536] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/mapper/centos-root ']'
[   21.548095] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.558316] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.558765] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' ']'
[   21.569236] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh'
[   21.569656] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/vg_home/lv_home ']'
[   21.580243] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): return 1
[   21.580656] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@32(): '[' -f /lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/work ']'
[   21.591385] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@36(): for job in '$hookdir/initqueue/*.sh'
[   21.591716] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@37(): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/*.sh' ']'
[   21.602730] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@37(): break
[   21.603303] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@42(): udevadm settle --timeout=0
[   21.614527] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@44(): for job in '$hookdir/initqueue/settled/*.sh'
[   21.614988] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@45(): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/settled/*.sh' ']'
[   21.626419] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@45(): break
[   21.626717] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@50(): udevadm settle --timeout=0
[   21.638645] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@53(): sleep 0.5
[   21.639102] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@55(): for i in '/run/systemd/ask-password/ask.*'
[   21.651010] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@56(): '[' -e '/run/systemd/ask-password/ask.*' ']'
[   21.651339] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@59(): '[' 1 -gt 240 ']'
[   21.663467] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@69(): main_loop=2
[   21.664030] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@70(): '[' 2 -gt 360 ']'
[   21.676355] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@24(): :
[   21.676815] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@26(): check_finished
[   21.689383] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@431(check_finished): local f
[   21.689816] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.702614] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.703054] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' ']'
[   21.716100] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh'
[   21.729616] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/root ']'
[   21.743112] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.756476] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.756768] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' ']'
[   21.770056] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh'
[   21.770360] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/swap ']'
[   21.783603] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.797050] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.810508] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' ']'
[   21.823987] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh'
[   21.837397] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/mapper/centos-root ']'
[   21.850730] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   21.864079] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   21.864406] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' ']'
[   21.877620] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh'
[   21.878174] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/vg_home/lv_home ']'
[   21.891691] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): return 1
[   21.892144] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@28(): udevadm settle --exit-if-exists=/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/work
[   21.905911] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@30(): check_finished
[   21.906341] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@431(check_finished): local f
[   21.920178] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   23.150102] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   23.168696] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh' ']'
[   23.169109] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh'
[   23.187580] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2froot.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/root ']'
[   23.187903] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   23.206377] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   23.206937] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh' ']'
[   23.225545] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh'
[   23.225988] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fcentos\x2fswap.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/centos/swap ']'
[   23.244615] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   23.245051] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   23.263629] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh' ']'
[   23.264088] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh'
[   23.282614] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fmapper\x2fcentos-root.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/mapper/centos-root ']'
[   23.282944] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@432(check_finished): for f in '$hookdir/initqueue/finished/*.sh'
[   23.301485] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@433(check_finished): '[' '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' = '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/*.sh' ']'
[   23.302048] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh' ']'
[   23.320693] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): . '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh'
[   23.321155] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: //lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fvg_home\x2flv_home.sh@1(source): '[' -e /dev/vg_home/lv_home ']'
[   23.339796] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /lib/dracut-lib.sh@434(check_finished): return 1
[   23.340238] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@32(): '[' -f /lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/work ']'
[   23.358792] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@36(): for job in '$hookdir/initqueue/*.sh'
[   23.359234] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@37(): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/*.sh' ']'
[   23.377687] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@37(): break
[   23.396408] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@42(): udevadm settle --timeout=0
[   23.396763] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@44(): for job in '$hookdir/initqueue/settled/*.sh'
[   23.415209] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@45(): '[' -e '/lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/settled/*.sh' ']'
[   23.433724] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@45(): break
[   23.452070] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@50(): udevadm settle --timeout=0
[   23.452397] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@53(): sleep 0.5
[   23.470413] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@55(): for i in '/run/systemd/ask-password/ask.*'
[   23.470959] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@56(): '[' -e '/run/systemd/ask-password/ask.*' ']'
[   23.471232] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@59(): '[' 2 -gt 240 ']'
[   23.471491] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@69(): main_loop=3
[   23.471747] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@70(): '[' 3 -gt 360 ']'
[   23.472009] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@24(): :
[   23.472273] my.domain dracut-initqueue[286]: /bin/dracut-initqueue@26(): check_finished
```

Comment: It looks like it's waiting for /dev/vg_home/lv_home to exist, getting a non-zero return code, running udevadm settle and trying again after sleeping half a second.
Any chance that logical volume doesn't exist or isn't mounting?

Comment: @jsbillings - Yes... I removed those hard drives for the time being while I investigate this issue. ^_^ They're a mirrored pair (software mirror through LVM) that simply mounts to `/home` and one of them _may_ be failing. However the issue was there even with them present. Hmm... maybe the log file would be different if the drives were there. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @jsbillings - OK, tried it. It's the same. Buut... looks like there's something wrong there. I get error messages about one of the drives and the whole VG/LV isn't coming online (at least not automatically). My current guess is that one of the drives really _is_ dead and that's why the system doesn't boot. Will keep on looking.